# Macbook air or Macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am iPhone app developer. i have develop application in my hackintosh PC but now i plan to buy a Macbook for app development.

I have two option one is **Macbook air** and second is **Macbook pro** 
both are coming in 13 inch screen.

Please help me to choose which is the best Macbook for application development ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either will do just fine for application development, and if you don't plan on doing heavy photo or video editing there's no need for the extra processing power of the MacBook Pro.

You might want to consider that the MacBook Air does not have a Retina display like the MacBook Pro, so the Pro display is of higher resolution, and you will have the option of scaling the display resolution to make everything smaller in order to get more screen real estate (but on a 13" display that might make stuff hard to read instead).

MacBook Air is also obviously lighter than the MacBook Pro, so it puts less (if only by a little bit) of a strain on your back and shoulders if you'll be carrying it around a lot.

If neither the optional extra screen real estate or processing power is important to you, and price is also important, go with the MacBook Air. If the price doesn't matter and you don't mind the extra weight, go with MacBook Pro.

Comment: In both Macbook xcode is running smoothly ?

Comment: @TejasPatel Yes!

Comment: @TejasPatel Obviously it depends on the kind of applications you're developing, but I would argue that if your app uses up the processing power of a MacBook Air, it's certainly going to run very slow on an iOS device, so that's more a problem of how you built the app, not a lack of processing power on the machine you're developing on.

Comment: so if i am going with Macbook pro then its chance to not faced this memory issue that i have to faced with Macbook air ?

Comment: @TejasPatel well, yes, if you're having problems with running out of memory then the base model of MacBook Pro 13" has 4GB more memory than the MacBook Air 13".

Comment: ok ok got it. i think according to you Macbook pro is more powerfull machine then Macbook air for development side . right ?